# How can a class template store either reference or value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Reading about [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) led me to wonder: how can I construct a class template such that it stores by reference if possible, or by value if it must?

That is, can I do something like this

```
template <class T>
class holder {
    T  obj_m;  // should be a reference if possible...
public:
    holder(T t) :obj_m { t } {}
}

auto 
hold_this(T && t) { return holder<T>(t); }
```

Except that when `hold_this()` is given an *lvalue* the holder will hold a reference, and when given an *rvalue* the holder will make a copy?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Except that when hold_this() is given an lvalue the holder will hold a reference, and when given an rvalue the holder will make a copy?

You already wrote it (minus the required `template <typename T>`). The deduction rules for a *forwarding reference* preserve value category as follows:

1. If `t` is bound to an lvalue of type `T2`, then `T = T2&`.
2. If `t` is bound to an rvalue of type `T2`, then `T = T2`.

It's those deduction rules that `std::forward` relies on to do its job. And why we need to pass the type to it as well.

The above means that you instantiate `holder` directly with `T2` in the rvalue case. Giving you exactly what you want. A copy is made.

As a matter of fact, two copies are made. Once to create the constructor argument `t`, and the other copy is to initialize `obj_m` from it. But we can get rid of it with some clever use of type_traits:

```
template <class T>
class holder {
    T  obj_m;  // should be a reference if possible...
public:
    holder(std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T> t) :obj_m { std::forward<T>(t) } {}
};

template<typename T>
auto hold_this(T && t) { return holder<T>(std::forward<T>(t)); }
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27ca91ba069c730b). We  use [`add_rvalue_reference_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) to make `t` be of the correct reference type in each case. And "simulate" the argument deduction which would make `obj_m { std::forward<T>(t) }` resolve to initializing `obj_m` from the correct reference type.

I say "simulate" because it's important to understand the constructor argument for `holder` cannot be a forwarding reference because the constructor itself is not templated.

---

By the way, since you tagged [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), we can also add a deduction guide to your example. If we define it as follows (with the [feedback from **T.C.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862454/how-can-a-class-template-store-either-reference-or-value/48862510#comment84745876_48862510) incorporated):

```
template <class T>
class holder {
    T  obj_m;  // should be a reference if possible...
public:
    holder(T&& t) :obj_m { std::forward<T>(t) } {}
};

template<typename T>
holder(T&&) -> holder<T>;
```

Then [this live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0L8L7nNTBii3UnLZ) shows you can define variables as `hold h1{t};` and `hold h2{test()};`, with the same deduced types as the function return values from before.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with nonreferenceable types, `add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` is exactly equivalent to `T&&`.

Comment: @T.C. - I don't suspect anyone will try and pass one of those in, so `T&&` as an alternative in the edited example it is. I must say though, that I find `add_rvalue_reference_t` less confusing for people who think `t` would be a forwarding reference.